# Parsing localhost rest using backbone

Tags: django, rest, backbone.js

I am testing a Rest server using Django Rest Framework. By following the tut from Django Rest website I successfully generated a proper API. But when I try to test with backbone.js to talk locally with that server, it seems fail to communicate together.

The server places at address: `http://localhost:8080/users/`
The client: `http://localhost/client`

This is the collection and the view in client

```
    var Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/apis/',
    });
```

The network after parsing shows **status: canceled** and **type: pending**

I suspect the port different caused the error. Could any point me out the correct way ? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The browser does not allow you to make POST/PUT ajax requests from `localhost(:80)` to `localhost:8080`, because of the Same Origin Policy requirement. In order for the browser to consider two addressed as having same origin, they must have the same protocol (http/https), domain name (localhost) and port number.

You can configure the web server at localhost:80 to proxy requests to localhost:8080. Most web servers support this functionality with a simple configuration change. If you are for instance using apache, see [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html).

Sample Apache proxy config:

```
ProxyPass /api http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse /api http://localhost:8080/
```

After this, you can access an address at `localhost:8080/users` with `localhost/api/users`:

```
var Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/api/users',
});
```

Comment: Where can I add those of line in the httpt.conf, I tried to add somewhere but it doesn't work. Thanks your reponse anyway

Comment: See apache documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html (The whole page in general, the "proxy" section in particular.

Comment: Consider changing the proxy config lines to have matching slashes on both sides, as in `/api http://localhost:8080` or `/api/ http://localhost:8080/`. Otherwise you might get incorrect URL substitution.